# combining variables in flex to form a variable or class name

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5, flexbuilder

I have an embedded image and the class name to be userd in source tag is a combination of 2 variables, i am confused how to do this, below is an iadea of what i am trying to do:

```
 [Embed (source="assets/image11_a.jpg")] public static const 11_a:Class;
 var first_part:String="11";
 var second_part:String="a";

and in mxml
<s:Image width="100" height="100" source="{first_part+second_part}"/>
```

above is just a small simplified example of what i am trying to do, actually the variables are getting populated from list.Basically i want to combine variable names to form the embedded image class name to be used in source of spark image.

Any help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<s:Image width="100" height="100" source="{this[first_part+second_part]}"/>
```

[Note: I'm not sure you're reasoning for this, and trying to piece together variable names at runtime seems like a bad idea to me, personally]

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but it is giving a warning message saying, databinding won't be able to detect changes when using square brackets...etc . So i guess there must be a better way out

Comment: If you explain what your use case, we may be able to offer an alternate solution.

Comment: That shouldn't matter, because what it wouldn't be able to detect is a change in a variable named 'first_part+second_part' (if such a thing were possible) changed. However, the change in the constituent variables should be enough to trigger the databinding expression to reevaluate.